# Can I delete ~/snap?

Tags: nautilus, files, filesystem, snap

I generally like to keep my home directory clean, so I'm not a fan of the ~/snap directory cluttering things up.  There don't seem to be any files in it, just some empty folders, so do I even need it? If it is needed, can I hide it somehow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have any snaps installed, they will likely use that directory. Some may appear empty, but they may have hidden folders inside. If you delete them, then you may lose config or data for the snaps you've installed.